Driving a 12V relay through transistor latches it in on mode, what I am doing wrong?
I am hooking up a 12V driven relay to a 5V TTL signal with a transistor like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Once I power the +5V on the base through the 1k resistor, the transistor will start conducting but it will latch, so that when I disconnect the +5V from the base it will remain on. Did I hit some breakdown voltage? I didn't know that existed.
I have also done the fly-back diode and a pull down resistor and it did still not help.

simulate this circuit
Interestingly these guys could also never make it work with a BJT: NPN BJT Relay Circuit will not turn off
I am replying to comments here:
Is it really TTL or CMOS? Actually for my breadboard setup right now it is neither, I am just putting the base to power-rail high, that is currently 5V. Ultimately the whole setup is supposed to be driven by 3.3V from an ESP32. Since the quick test already failed I was not even beginning to worry about that.
As to whether the transistors are fried, I am not sure. The strange thing is that once I disconnect the 12V, the relay will of course disengage and when I put the power on again, then again I put the base to high will engage the relay. The behavior of the transistor did not change between first and second attempt. I also swapped in a new transistor once I had the diode in the circuit, and got the same result. I am pretty sure I know where the collector and emitter is on an NPN in a TO92 package, the flat side is like the bar in the circuit symbol, the middle is the base, and holding the round side to the left, the top is the collector and the bottom the emitter.

Try adding a pull-down resistor, about 15-22 kOhm, from base to ground and adding a simple diode across the coil -- arrange the diode so that it's anode is towards ground and the cathode towards the +12. See if that makes a difference.

transistor will open usually means that it stops conducting ... please stop using terms such as open and closed, and start using conducting and non-conducting

@periblepsis didn't help, strangely, I also tried two different diodes and checked them, and tried to swap the transistor in case I had already fried that, but to no avail.

You say you "power on the base" and "disconnect the +5V", but you have "TTL in" on the schematic. What is the actual circuit driving the base?

Are you sure you have the transistor pinout correct? Should be C-B-E from the front, leads down. You can confirm with diode function on a multimeter. There are three common transistor pinouts in TO92. For example, a C1815 Japanese standard transistor installed as if it was a BC547 will behave has you describe, even though both transistors will work if connected properly.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany yes I am sure. If I didn't have it correct it wouldn't turn on. My problem is it doesn't turn off.

@GuntherSchadow Not really true - if you got it reversed (US pinout) then the relay might not pull in with the 9V-ish breakdown in reverse active mode, but the 3-4V could be enough to keep it from dropping out.

@GuntherSchadow Are you really using a TTL signal? Or is it a CMOS signal? TTL is a very particular terminology, meaning that the lower range of high level is fairly low 2V, way too low for e.g. symmetric 5V CMOS logic.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany you were right! I had the transistor in reverse! Duh!

@GuntherSchadow - Thanks for coming back with the solution. However it should be posted as an answer, that's why the concept of a self-answer exists, to allow an OP to post the solution to their own question, if they solve it in a different way than any other answer. || It would be polite to credit Spehro 'speff' Pefhany in that self-answer, since he initially raised the concern in comments. || If you've gone offline then after a while,  I can generate an answer for you, from the new information you added into the question. TY

This EBC/CBE/ECB tomfoolery is why I abandoned TO-92 transistors in favor of SOT-23. SOT's are standardized.

@GuntherSchadow - As I explained, I have moved the solution which you kindly added, into an answer. || I found that the transistor pinout image in the solution part of the question, was copied from elsewhere but was missing the required reference. Therefore when I created the answer from the solution you added (which included that copied image), I found & included a reference for that image. Please note that site rule for referencing. Just FYI, copying/adapting material from SE should follow this process. TY


I am hooking up a 12V driven relay to a 5V TTL signal with a transistor like this

The transistor is now destroyed.

the transistor will start conducting but it will latch

A transistor that is presumably permanently "latched on" is colloquialism for a blown transistor.

I have also done the fly-back diode and a pull down resistor like this:

Too late I'm afraid.

these guys could also never make it work with a BJT

Then let's not copy their mistakes :) I assure you it works perfectly fine with a BJT if the circuit is designed and laid out correctly. Relays of all sizes were driven with BJTs for well over half a century now. It's old news by now. If it doesn't work, it definitely means the circuit is wrong or the transistor is dead or whatnot. The circuit is dead simple and very dependable.

The 12V coil of the relay only draws 30mA of current. The base current can be 1mA or less. So 1kΩ base resistor is unnecessarily low.
I would put that circuit together like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The voltage developed across D1 and D2 ensures fast turn-off of the relay. D3 and D4 protect the transistor from the effects of ground bounce due to poor layout of fault currents elsewhere in the system.
Do not try this circuit without the diodes in place. The new (!) transistor is likely to get damaged as well otherwise. The old transistors you got that were tried with this circuit without diodes should be considered non-functional unless shown otherwise.
If you ask "why all those diodes?" - well, you tried without them and things didn't work out so well. These diodes essentially guarantee that the transistor's limits will not be exceeded. As your problem was blown transitors, that seems a reasonable route to take. Remember that you tried without the diodes already.
Normally only the flyback diode would be necessary, but there are some layout or other problems in your circuit that make the other diodes also needed to protect the poor transistor.

When testing this circuit, you need to keep track of transistor's temperature. It is not meant to get hot in normal operation. If it is getting hot then either it's already destroyed, or the base current is insufficient to turn the transistor ON. In that case, you'd need a second transistor to drive the first one:

simulate this circuit

Thank you! So D1, D2 and D4 are 15V Zener diodes? How important is the exact type 1N4148? Does it matter given that the voltages and currents are probably all within the limits of just any old diode? And while we are at it: most of these circuits I see published have Q1 as a 2N2222, does that matter as opposed to BC547B (C or A)? And finally, if my signal is 3.3V CMOS (from an ESP32) does that change anything? Perhaps R1 being back to 1kOhm?

The OP Gunther Schadow has solved the problem as follows:


Transistor Was Reversed!
NO! I am actually super stupid! I had the transistor reversed! The
round side is to be on the right, then the collector is on top! I had
worked with them all day long and did everything right, just on this
breadboard test I did it wrong! And lo and behold with or without the
diode, the transistor works turning on and off all fine once in
correctly. Perhaps this relay has this pair of Zener diodes in there
or the transistors survived the surge. I actually turned it on and off
a few dozen times without the diode and nothing stopped working.
Note to self: don't assume anything!


Image source: ilovefuzz.com - DIY Ibanez Standard Fuzz? by eatyourguitar

PS: I hooked up a scope to trigger on the falling edge of the control
line, and recorded the voltage on the collector. With and without the
diode.
With the diode the falling edge on the base is mirrored by the rising
edge on the collector and it's all fair and square as it should.
Without the diode we get a big spike of easily 50V (chopped off even
by the scope) and coming down while pulling even the base into a
negative ripple. So it's definitely bad, but I don't have any evidence
for the transistor damaged. It continue to switch on and off happily.
I also checked currents on base, raw coil, and collector. First the
raw coil on 12V to ground pulls 30 mA. With the transistor too, so I
know the transistor is full on. With the base resistor at 1 kΩ I get
4.5 mA flowing into the base, and I can even use 10 kΩ and it still works with 0.4 mA flowing into the base.
I have also hooked the control to 3.3V and it still works, although I
haven't tested with the 10 kΩ. Nor have I used an actual TTL or CMOS
signal, I could hook up an oscillator and a buffer or inverter of the
respective logic type to see how reliable and fast the relay switches,
but I think I will just settle on 4.7 kΩ and that will be it.
So the moral of the story is

Don't assume anything about those TO92 packages
BJTs really do work with C and E reversed, for simple logic signal switching at low current and low frequency you might not even
notice the error
Hey, those BC247 BJTs aren't that fragile to get fried instantly
I proceed without all those Zener diodes and keep it simple.



(This solution was originally added into the question by the OP and has been moved into this answer with credit to its author, in accordance with the CC BY-SA 4.0 license. I have applied the approach explained here to post someone else's content as an answer and set the answer to "Community wiki" so that I don't earn any points from upvotes on this answer, as it isn't my solution.)
(In accordance with the license, I have modified the text above to add non-breaking spaces, to avoid values being split from units, and to add the missing reference for the copied transistor pinout image.)

To give credit where it's due, the possibility that the cause was reversed transistor pinout was originally raised by Spehro 'speff' Pefhany in comments below the question.
